# can't enable windows authentication in IIS

Tags: iis, iis-7, windows-authentication

I've disabled anonymous authentication and I've enabled Windows authentication on my website in IIS 7. 
Now, when I browse to the website (http://webserver), Internet Explorer keeps prompting me for a username/password. Since I'm on the intranet, IE should pass on my credentials automatically...

What's more is that if I enter my credentials, they are not even recognized.

I'm out of ideas, if anyone could help....

Comment: Should be a ServerFault question, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/258063

Comment: I am getting the exact same issue, did you ever resolve this?